# Karate : Match a response to be a string or null

Tags: karate

[image]

I want to know how can we use the OR condition to check for a variable to either contain a certain String or null

To be specific I want to compare a variable using OR but for two different data type

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution, there may be others:

```
* def fun = x => !x || x.includes('hello')

* def data1 = null
* def data2 = 'foo hello bar'
* match data1 == '#? fun(_)'
* match data2 == '#? fun(_)'
```

Refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#self-validation-expressions